# Swift Playgrounds (iPad) does not build an app with implemented ARSessionDelegate.session(_:didUpdate:) functions

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground, ipad-playgrounds

I found an error while trying to implement a SwiftUI representation of `ARView` with `ARSessionDelegate` based on Apple’s official example [“Building an immersive experience with RealityKit”](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/building_an_immersive_experience_with_realitykit).

There is the error

> Method '__preview__session(_:didUpdate:)' with Objective-C selector '__preview__session:didUpdate:' conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector

I prepared the following sample to easily reproduce this.

```swift
import ARKit
import RealityKit
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RealityKitView()
    }
}

private struct RealityKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
    class Coordinator: NSObject, ARSessionDelegate {
        func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) { }
        func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) { }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator { Coordinator() }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let view = ARView()
        let session = view.session
        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        config.planeDetection = [.horizontal]
        session.run(config)
        session.delegate = context.coordinator
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ view: A.  RView, context: Context) { }
}
```

A quite interesting moment is that this code above can be successfully built with a general Swift Playgrounds’ playground or Xcode but not within Swift Playgrounds' app.

**Are there any workarounds?**

Also, found another weird error `'Scene' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context` from the same Apple’s Underwater example (`FoodPool.swift`). I simplified the content to clarify where the problem is, however, there is nothing wrong with this code.

```
import RealityKit

class FoodPool {
    private let arView: ARView
    private var scene: Scene { arView.scene } // Error: 'Scene' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
    
    init(arView: ARView) { 
        self.arView = arView
    }
}
```

Apart from the `ARSessionDelegate` problem this one can be resolved with using `arView.scene` directly (removed line 5 will help).

Overall, seems like there is hidden much more complicated problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Workaround

**Given** a file with a *fake* :D error, and planned changes are done in the file, **when** another valid file is chosen, and the project is reloaded (or Swift Playgrounds is restated), **then** the project could be run successfully straight away if there are no other errors.

This helped me with the `ARSessionDelegate` problem and running [the Underwater example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/building_an_immersive_experience_with_realitykit) on iPad.